# How to reverse a single string in python

Tags: python

I don't know how to get a single string to reserve. So say I have '>' but I want to reserve it to make it '<'.

I know to reserve a string you would go:

```
arrow = 'arrow'
reverse_arrow = arrow[::-1]
print(reverse_arrow)
```

But that doesn't seem to work if I want to reserve a single string. How do I reserve a single string from '>' to make it '<'?

Comment: `[::-1]` reversed the order of the characters in the string, you will have to individually replace each instance of `>` with `<`.

Comment: `arrow[::-1]` ? Yea this works for me, not sure why you don't think this works?

Comment: @AlexHall Even that website doesn't change `>` to `<`

Comment: Make a dictionary whose keys are the characters that need to be reversed like that, and the values are the replacement character. Then go through the reversed string and replace each of these characters with the replacement.

Comment: You're using a different meaning of the word "reverse" here.  Usually it means "to arrange in reverse order", i.e. `abcd` becomes `dcba`.  But you are asking for a glyph to be _flipped on its vertical axis_, which is entirely different.  I don't know of any way to do this automatically.  If you only need to work with bracket pairs, i.e. `()`, `[]`, `{}` etc. it might be possible...

Comment: @JohnGordon Oh so that's what he wanted. `>` is usually a direction indicator as well. I was so confused haha.

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting a reversed display then you need to import a font library with reversed characters (such as Mirror Image). Just not sure what you are wanting or where/how you are wanting to use this function...